# How to change location of favIcon in angular 11 based on some condition

Tags: javascript, html, angular, favicon, angular11

I am using Angular 11 in which I am able to load/show the *favicon* which is located in the `src` folder. But my requirement is to make *favicon* configurable if I have put its location in the config variable so that it would take the location of *favicon* based on the value which I have provided in the config file. Note: we are changing the config variable only before deployment.

I have tried using many things but nothing is working for me. Only I am able to get the *favicon* which is located in the source folder.
In `app.component.html`

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <base href="./">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" id ="favIcon"  href="assets/{{favIcon}}">
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

In `app.component.ts` file, `favIcon` variable is set to `images/favicon1.ico`

We have tried changing this by JavaScript using document selector in `app.component.ts`

```
this.favicon = document.getElementById('favIcon');
this.favicon.href = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("assets/images/rdh-favIcon.ico");
```

could you please provide any solution so that I can use a different *favicon* from a different location?

In angular.json

```
 "assets": ["src/favicon.ico",
             "src/assets"],
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `app.component.html`

```
<link rel="icon" id ="favIcon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

In your `app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent {
  favIcon: HTMLLinkElement = document.querySelector('#favIcon');

  changeIcon() {
    this.favIcon.href = 'https://www.google.com/favicon.ico';
  }
}
```

For `Angular 12.x` replace

`favIcon: HTMLLinkElement = document.querySelector('#favIcon')`

with

`favIcon: any = document.querySelector('#favIcon')`

Don't forget to add a `button` somewhere in your `app.component.html` that excutes this `changeIcon()` function.

i.e.

```
<button (click)="changeIcon()">Change favicon</button>
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: We want to change favicon not on a button click but before loading the page